# Go: unable to render external stylesheets

Tags: go

I'm trying to render external stylesheets. I'm not sure why this is not working:

GO:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/image/", imageHandler)
    http.Handle("/layout/", http.StripPrefix("/layout/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("layout"))))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Dir structure:

```
gocode
    layout
        stylesheets
            home.css
    home.html
main.go
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/home.css" />
```

Whats wrong? I followed the example here: [Rendering CSS in a Go Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302020/rendering-css-in-a-go-web-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file server is at `/layout/`, so it should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/layout/stylesheets/home.css" />
```