# 404 page not found - Go rendering css file

Tags: html, css, go, http-status-code-404, go-templates

I'm currently working in Go. I created a web server on my local machine. I followed the instruction on this page [Rendering CSS in a Go Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302020/rendering-css-in-a-go-web-application)
but I'm still getting the 404 error that the program can't seem to find where my css file is. My directory is as follows.

In `src` folder contains `css/somefilename.css`, `src` also contains `server/server.go`.

The code inside my `server.go` file is as follows.

```
http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))))
```

When I go to `localhost:8080/css/` I get 404 page not found. I'm also using templates to render the html code. The templates are in the folder

```
src/templates/layout.html
```

the html code is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/css490.css" />
```

Comment: Would that work better if you put the full path of the `css` folder in `http.FileServer(http.Dir("/full/path/of/css")`?

Comment: Yes when i use the full path it works as expected. The only gripe i have is why it work on my friend machine (mac) with the code above but when i ran it on my machine (windows) it didn't work. We literally have the same file paths for the css file to the server.go

Comment: Just for testing, would replacing `"css"` with `filepath.FromSlash(path.Clean("css")` work better (and for any platform)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't specify full path for the `css` folder just a relative one, whether your css files are found depends on the *folder you run your application from* (the working directory, this is what relative paths are resolved to).

For example if you start your application from your `src` with `go run server/server.go` it will work. If you start it from your `src/server` folder with `go run server.go`, it will not work. Also if you create a native executable from your app which is put into the `bin` folder and you start that from the `bin` folder, this also won't work because the `css` folder is not in the `bin` folder.

Either start it with `go run server/server.go` from the `src` folder, or copy the `css` folder to your `bin` folder and start the executable from the `bin` folder and it should work (but in this case you also have to copy other static files like html templates).

Comment: This seems to trip a lot of people up - all the time.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. i thought that i was running my files from src/server but i was using the command go install server which creates an executable in the bin folder.