# Go Lang - Where in directory structure to place images for use in HTML template?

Tags: html, image, go

I've just started working with GO and am creating a simple web interface.  I have a working GO server, an HTML template called "survey.gtpl" which is served up by the server as expected, and a logo I would like displayed on the web page.  No matter where I place the image within the workspace directory structure or what I put as the  src path, the image will not load.

Here is the current directory structure:

```
+ workspace
    + bin
        server.exe
    + src
        + github.com
            + cwrighta70
                + web
                    server.go
    LogoColor.jpg
    survey.gtpl
```

And here is the path within the "survey.gtpl" template"

```
<img src = "LogoColor.jpg" alt="Logo" width="789px" height="182px">
```

I've tried putting the image in it's own directory within the workspace, like `workspace/img/LogoColor.jpg`.  I've also tried putting it in with the web server executable in `workspace/bin/LogoColor.jpg`.  All I get in the browser is the Alt text.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

- Chris

Comment: Where you put the images has nothing to do with the template. The handler that serves those files has to be able to find them.

Comment: you should make a folder named `public` or `html` or `web`, put your static resources there, then host that folder with e.g. [gin-gonic/contrib/static](https://github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/blob/master/static/static_test.go#L62)

Comment: Use your browser debugging tools and verify that your server is sending the correct path.

Comment: Some related questions: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580043); [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293452); [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945310)

Comment: Also you might find this useful: [how to reference a relative file from code and tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059023/how-to-reference-a-relative-file-from-code-and-tests)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if found a couple different ways to do this.  First, my actual solution was to port my app to a CGI rather than a Go Web Server.  This took away the need to serve up assets separately.

However, for those who have a Go web server and need to get this figured out, here's how I did it.  I placed all of my resources (i.e., images, stylesheets, etc) in a "resources" directory at the root of where the app was being run, then added a `HandleFunc` for this URL in the main as shown here:

```
router := http.NewServeMux()
router.HandleFunc(getURL("/view/"), viewHandler)
router.HandleFunc(getURL("/resources/"), serveAssets)
```

Then, the `serveAssets` function attempts to open each resource, and if successful calls `ServeContent` as shown:

```
func serveAssets(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()

    file, err := os.Open(docRoot + r.URL.String())
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    modeTime := time.Now()
    http.ServeContent(w, r, docRoon+r.URL.String(), modeTime, file)
}
```

That should do it!