# Can't read file in GoLang

Tags: go, static-files

I am new to GoLang dev and am trying to make a simple web-app. I have been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AiRhWG-2nGU.

However I can not even serve the index.html file.

This is my code

```
func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
        panic(e)
    }
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Index functoin")
    indexHTML, err := ioutil.ReadFile("index.html")
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(indexHTML)
    w.Write(indexHTML)
}
```

and this is the error produced

```
Index functoin
open index.html: no such file or directory
```

My tree structure is like so

```
BasicWebServer/
BasicWebServer/main.go
BasicWebServer/index.html
BasicWebServer/static/
BasicWebServer/static/index.html
```

All I want is to be able to serve the index.html since it is a AngularJS app which is already running smoothly. I tried with static files like so

```
router := NewRouter()
s := http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/")))
```

but it did not work so I am now trying the most basic approach I could think of.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Your files need to be relative to the working directory of your server process. The location in the source has nothing to do with where you run the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [404 page not found - Go rendering css file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293452/404-page-not-found-go-rendering-css-file)

Comment: Also related / possible duplicate of [Why do I need to use http.StripPrefix to access my static files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945310/why-do-i-need-to-use-http-stripprefix-to-access-my-static-files)

Comment: Guys this has nothing to do with the problem that I can not read a file correctly from the FileSystem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `BasicWebServer/main.go` to show `BasicWebServer/index.html`, not the one inside the `static` folder, then it seems you didn't properly configure the HTTP server.

Here's your code, with package declaration, imports and a `main` function working as you expected.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
        panic(e)
    }
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Index functoin")
    indexHTML, err := ioutil.ReadFile("index.html")
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(indexHTML)
    w.Write(indexHTML)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", Index)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    check(err)
}
```

Comment: Hey, man. Thank you for the answer. I just tried it and it did not work. I get " The localhost page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE " again. What i did was to copy your source, paste it in a new file main2.go, and run " go run BasicWebServer/main2.go ". The index.html file is in the same dir as main2.go ....

Comment: Index functoin22222
open index.html: no such file or directory
....

This is the output in the console

Comment: If i supply the full path I get the correct file though. However I do not want to have to supply the full path since this means all static imports will be bound to my set-up. What can we do about this ?

Comment: There's `http.StripPrefix` for that. You shouldn't have such problems with relative paths. Let me give it a try and I'll link you an example.

Comment: Also, I see you run the application using `go run BasicWebServer/main2.go` this means your current working directory is different to the one you are using in your application. That's something we can work with too.

Comment: I have no idea man. I literally started this week so everything is new to me :D THanks for the help

Comment: Go inside `BasicWebServer` directory, then `go run main2.go`, your relative path will work just fine.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you. Any comment on what is going on. It feels kind of strange to run the app from within its inner folders ... Also my static files are still not showing up :X I can make a separate question for this if needed

Comment: I will make another question for the static files after I give it another try :D sorry to bother you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115409/discussion-between-toqueteos-and-mp3por).