# Golang web server not serving static files

Tags: go, webserver, http-status-code-404, static-files

I'm fairly certain that I've overlooked something obvious, but I'm not sure what. I'm building a simple web application that serves up templated pages of books. The template works fine, and the path for the image seems to be populating correctly, but I keep getting a 404 error for the image itself.

Here is the template:

```
<h1>{{.Title}}</h1>
<h2>{{.Author.Name}}</h2>
<image src="../images/{{.ImageURI}}" />
```

and here is the application itself:

```
package main
import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/user/marketplace/typelibrary"
)

var books []typelibrary.Book

func ItemHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    var selected typelibrary.Book       
    //Retrieve item data
    for _, item := range books {
        if item.ID == params["id"] {
            selected = item
            break
        }
    }
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("./templates/book.html")
    t.Execute(w, selected)
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    books = append(books, typelibrary.Book{ID: "1", Title: "The Fellowship of the Ring", ImageURI: "LotR-FotR.jpg", Author: &typelibrary.Author{Name: "JRR Tolkien"}})
    books = append(books, typelibrary.Book{ID: "2", Title: "The Two Towers", ImageURI: "LotR-tTT.jpg", Author: &typelibrary.Author{Name: "JRR Tolkien"}})
    books = append(books, typelibrary.Book{ID: "3", Title: "The Return of the King", ImageURI: "LotR-RotK.jpg", Author: &typelibrary.Author{Name: "JRR Tolkien"}})
    books = append(books, typelibrary.Book{ID: "4", Title: "Monster Hunter International", ImageURI: "MHI1.jpg", Author: &typelibrary.Author{Name: "Larry Correia"}})

    router.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
    router.Handle("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../images/")))
    router.HandleFunc("/item/{id}", ItemHandler).Methods("GET")

    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler:      router,
        Addr:         ":8080",
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  10 * time.Second,
    }
    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}
```

The images are stored in the `images` subdirectory, directly below the directory where the executable is. When I attempt to view the broken image in the page, the path shows up as `localhost:8080/images/[imagename]` but gives a 404 error. What configuration or routing options am I missing here?

Comment: You are almost certainly passing the wrong path to `http.Dir`.  Why `../`?  Are you executing the server from a subdirectory? I'd expect you'd want `./images/` based on your description.

Comment: @Flimzy You are correct, it should properly be `./images/`, however the problem persists either way.

Comment: We don't know your directory structure and how you start your server, but these answers contain the solution: [404 page not found - Go rendering css file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293452/404-page-not-found-go-rendering-css-file/28294524#28294524); and [Why do I need to use http.StripPrefix to access my static files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945310/why-do-i-need-to-use-http-stripprefix-to-access-my-static-files/27946132#27946132)

Comment: It's really going to depend on where the images are relative to _the working directory when you execute the binary_. Another approach would be to use a configuration value (from a config file, env var, or CLI flag) to pass in the root path where your content files can be found, and use that rather than relative paths.

Comment: To know. What is `github.com/user/marketplace/typelibrary`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating your route incorrectly to serve your images. The `Router.Handle()` method matches URLs with the `Path()` matcher, which matches the entire path, while you actually want to match any path that starts with "/image/". Instead, create the route with the `PathPrefix()` matcher:

```
var imgServer = http.FileServer(http.Dir("./images/"))
router.PathPrefix("/images/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/images/", imgServer))
```

See https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.Handle for more information.