# http.FileServer is sending "404 page not found"

Tags: go

I'm trying to serve static files via http.FileServer, however it never sends back the directory I'm asking for. The code is snipped below:

```
func main() {

fmt.Println("Serving Files")
http.HandleFunc("/", homeFunc)
http.HandleFunc("/search", searchFunc)
http.Handle("/tmp/",
    http.StripPrefix("/tmp/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/assets"))))

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

When visiting mywebsite.com/tmp/, text appears saying "404 page not found." A little help in case I'm missing something would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here's the file architecture:

```
main folder
|
|-/Assets
|--(assets)
|
|-main.go
```

Comment: Please check [Why do I need to use http.StripPrefix to access my static files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945310/why-do-i-need-to-use-http-stripprefix-to-access-my-static-files/27946132#27946132); and [404 page not found - Go rendering css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293452/404-page-not-found-go-rendering-css-file/28294524#28294524).

Comment: The go file is run from "/", attempting to find assets from the /assets file. Neither of those responses have helped me in this situation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the directory `/assets` exist? Note that `/assets` is an absolute path, so it must be at the root of your filesystem. If you want something in the working directory where you're executing your program, you should use `./assets`.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. This issue has bugged me for weeks

Comment: i changed to "./assets" and still 404

Answer (score 1):

If you use relative path, you can check what your path is.

```
import (
"fmt"
"os"
)

dir, _ := os.Getwd()
fmt.Println("current path :" + dir)
```