# How to include css to go lang app

Tags: css, web-applications, go

I have problem with adding some CSS to my web app, which is created with go lang. `main.go` and html file are included to root directory and `style.css` is included to `root/css` directory

my .*go code is

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func main(){

    http.HandleFunc("/home", mainViewHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func mainViewHandler(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter,request *http.Request){

    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("main.html")
    t.Execute(responseWriter, 0)
}
```

and html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="todo/style.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Main Page</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Take your choice</h2>
        <a href="/edit">Edit</a>
        <a href="/add">Add</a>
        <a href="/list">List</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering CSS in a Go Web Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302020/rendering-css-in-a-go-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell go to serve files from root/css directory. And keep in mind that root/css should be in the working folder of your app when you're running it.

I don't use http package directly, but believe in your case it should be as follows (before ListenAndServe):

```
http.Handle("/todo/", http.StripPrefix("root/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("root/css"))))
```

But you might need to adjust it according to your actual folders configuration.

See documentation [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer_stripPrefix)

Comment: I try this solution more time before and it's not working

Comment: I had to add one "." before my path -_- ... thanks for your tip.